# Unity Firebase Authentication retrieve id token after sign in with Apple

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication, access-token, sign-in-apple

I made a feature where user can sign in Apple in Android using Unity Firebase. The code is:

```
        var providerData = new FederatedOAuthProviderData
        {
            ProviderId = "apple.com"
        };
        var provider = new FederatedOAuthProvider();
        provider.SetProviderData(providerData);
        await auth.SignInWithProviderAsync(provider).ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            var result = task.Result;
        });
```

my question is: how to retrieve apple id token from task.Result ?

edit: the data return contains 2 parts:

1. user info

   {
   "PhotoUrl": null,
   "DisplayName": "",
   "Email": "bangminhkiet@hoppergames.io",
   "IsAnonymous": false,
   "IsEmailVerified": true,
   "Metadata": {
   "LastSignInTimestamp": 1660117698962,
   "CreationTimestamp": 1660116775373
   },
   "PhoneNumber": "",
   "ProviderData": [
   {
   "PhotoUrl": null,
   "UserId": "elba7GqsGccUvQiYnEZr5KTtHlv2",
   "Email": "bangminhkiet@hoppergames.io",
   "DisplayName": "",
   "ProviderId": "firebase"
   },
   {
   "PhotoUrl": null,
   "UserId": "000435.d5a5ca436f7645f992af1e1cc4d8e97b.0728",
   "Email": "bangminhkiet@hoppergames.io",
   "DisplayName": "",
   "ProviderId": "apple.com"
   }
   ],
   "ProviderId": "firebase",
   "UserId": "elba7GqsGccUvQiYnEZr5KTtHlv2"
   }
2. extra info
   {
   "Profile": {
   "at_hash": "W89x3Dkr7ri-mMHu2bHdiw",
   "aud": "com.m.obirix.mbgk.web",
   "auth_time": 1660117696,
   "email": "bangminhkiet@hoppergames.io",
   "email_verified": "true",
   "exp": 1660204098,
   "iat": 1660117698,
   "iss": "https://appleid.apple.com",
   "nonce_supported": true,
   "sub": "000435.d5a5ca436f7645f992af1e1cc4d8e97b.0728"
   },
   "ProviderId": "apple.com",
   "UserName": "",
   "UpdatedCredential": {
   "Provider": ""
   }
   }

Comment: Well what is the format of the result. What data does it give you

Comment: I added data return @BugFinder

Comment: So you have a class or 2 you can make and populate from the json.   Which contains a username which I’m guessing you blanked (for good reason) but there’s certainly some form of Id in there you can use so yes. You can